# CW: City Information Required for product type::local_conditions' Here Map

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, here-maps-rest

I am trying to get information about the weather but when I make a simple post query to api gets that result

```
`https://weather.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json?app_id=${appId}&app_code=${appCode}&product=observation&name=${city}`
{ Type: 'Invalid Request',
[0]   Message:
[0]    [ 'CW: City Information Required for product type::local_conditions' ] }
```

in the documentation 'https://developer.here.com' I can not find a solution for this error

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly straightforward, the code below is working for me:

```
const request = require('request');

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://weather.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json',
    qs: {
        app_id: appId, // Put your APP_ID here
        app_code: appCode, // Put your APP_CODE here
        product: 'observation',
        name: 'Berlin' // Put whichever location here
    }
}

request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error("An error has occurred: ", error);
    } else {
        console.log("Response body: ", body);
    }
});
```